Including specific records using a LEFT Join in SQL Server
I have two tables joined through a left join. I want to include all records in the Borrowers table but only records where Loan_Type = 'Auto' in the Loans table.
Here is all of the code in a working SQL Fiddle example:
SQLFiddle


@LasseV.Karlsen - that works as I wanted. Thanks very much.

Instead of specifying the criteria in the WHERE clause, simply add the criteria to the join instead:
Rewrite this:
LEFT JOIN Loans l ON b.Loan_ID = l.Loan_ID
WHERE l.loan_type = 'Auto'

to this:
LEFT JOIN Loans l ON b.Loan_ID = l.Loan_ID AND l.loan_type = 'Auto'

WHERE filters the entire row from the resultset, whereas additional criteria in the joins will only filter that part of the join.
